# Swift: Header of UICollectionViewController overlaps cells

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionreusableview

I have a `UICollectionViewController` and want to add a custom header.

I checked `Section Header` in the Interface Builder within my CollectionViewController and implemented in my subclass of it the `viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind` function.

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {

    switch kind {

    case UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader:

        let headerView = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: "myHeaderIdentifier", for: indexPath)

        // !! NOT WORKING PROPERLY
        // sectionHeader overlaps other cells

        headerView.backgroundColor = UIColor(hue: 0.9, saturation: 1.0, brightness: 0.9, alpha: 1.0)
        headerView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 250.0)

        return headerView

    default:
        assert(false, "Unexpected element kind")
    }

}
```

The changes take effect, but the header (the pink area in the screenshot below) now overlaps the regular cells within the collectionView.

[image]

What am I doing wrong? 
Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public func layoutAttributesForSupplementaryElementOfKind(kind: String, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes?
```

Here I believe you should be able to set the frame / height

There's also `headerReferenceSize` in `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` that you can set when creating your `collectionView` if it's going to be static

Comment: Thank you, Magoo! Using FlowLayout led me into the right direction, `headerReferenceSize` does exactly what I wanted to achieve. `let flowLayout =  self.collectionView?.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout`

Comment: Perfect, glad you got it sorted

Answer (score 2):

Use this method from the `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` protocol:

```
optional func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, 
                  layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, 
      referenceSizeForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 250.0)
}
```

Make sure to set your class as the flow layout's delegate. You can find more information [here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicollectionviewdelegateflowlayout/1617702-collectionview).

Comment: This function returns a CGSize object not an Integer